# In AndroidViewModel, how to use the received application property?

Tags: android, kotlin, constructor, android-viewmodel

A simple `AndroidViewModel` looks like

```
class AppViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {...}
```

Now, to access the `application` property all over the model, we need to add a `val`/`var` to it (per my knowledge).

```
class AppViewModel(val application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {...}
```

This however gives error, saying

```
Accidental Override: The following declarations have the same JVM signature: getApplication()
```

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have access, you can use this property inside your class:

```
private val db = SomeDB.getInstance(application)
```

but not inside class methods, you must pass it manually:

```
fun myViewModelMethod(application: Application = application, ...) {}
```

However, you can declare new property inside your viewmodel:

```
class AppViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    val app = application
...
}
```

and use it anywhere inside.

Comment: Ok I don't know what your mean by the db thingy, but your final example is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: And.. suddenly you're at a higher reputation than me... I have an account with more than 2000 reputation but it got suspended. I created another account, and they deleted it. If you want to learn something, this is an adequate site, but do not explicitly work on the site only to gain reputation, since they will take it all away from you, without prior notice....